# git push error "Error:Commit message must contain a workItem ID"

Tags: git, push

when I push my repo I got error message below, and my colleague can push normally.
how can I fix this? Thanks!

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "add files"

$ git push 
Counting objects: 43, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 6.80 MiB | 17.28 MiB/s, done.
Total 43 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: 
remote: **********************************************************************
remote: *  Error: Commit message must contain a workItem ID(for example, EL-
remote: *    91), to which commit will be linked!
remote: *  Commit interrupted.
remote: **********************************************************************
remote: 
remote: Commit Aborted!
To http://10.99.1.1/name/name/name.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://10.99.1.1/name/name/name.git'
```

Answer (score 4):

All lines beginning with `remote:` come from some sort of custom software installed at the other end, not from Git.

Take the word `remote:` away from each line and read the message.  If it tells you how to fix the problem, follow the instructions.  If it does not tell you how to fix the problem, complain to the people who generated those text lines.  Git itself cannot help you because the problem has nothing to do with Git.

In this case, the message seems reasonably clear to me: they (whoever they are) have a required form for Git commit messages, and you wrote a Git commit message that does not conform to the required form.  Use `git rebase -i` or `git commit --amend` to modify your commit message(s) to make them conform to the required form.